# php syntax errors not showing with classes

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am using this code to show syntax errors in php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

It works well but as soon as I start working with classes, errors don't show anymore for some classes (the core classes included in my index.php). I don't know why but they are still displayed in the action of the controller.

Anybody has an idea of what's going on and how to solve this problem without changing the php.ini ?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can't enable error_reporting this way in a file that already contains syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i still don't get it. Why am i still able to get syntax errors from the action (the view function) of my controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code but its working my case

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but still not working. I am still getting a blank page with this code.